# GLSL phong shaders, debugging

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am looking for some help debugging my GLSL phong shading code. Here is my vertex shader:

```
layout(std140) uniform Matrices {
    mat4 model[1024];
};

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform mat4 view; // from lookAt() 
uniform mat4 projection; // perspective projection 

out vec3 Position;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec4 lightPosEye;

void main() {
    mat4 modelView = view * model[gl_InstanceID];
    mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelView)));
    //mat3 normalMatrix = mat3(modelView);

    vec4 lightPos = vec4(350, 350, 350, 1);
    lightPosEye = modelView * lightPos;

    Position = vec3(modelView * vertexCoord);
    Normal = normalize(normalMatrix * vertexNormal);

    gl_Position = projection * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

and here is my fragment shader:

```
in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec4 lightPosEye;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

vec3 ads() {
    vec3 Ka = vec3(0, 0.5, 0);
    vec3 Kd = vec3(0, 0.5, 0);
    vec3 Ks = vec3(0, 0.1, 0);
    vec3 intensity = vec3(0.3, 0.5, 0.0);
    float shininess = 0.1;

    vec3 n = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(lightPosEye) - Position);
    vec3 v = normalize(vec3(-Position));
    vec3 r = reflect(-s, n);

    return intensity * (Ka + Kd * max(dot(s, n), 0.0) + Ks * pow(max(dot(r,v), 0.0), shininess));
}

void main() {
    FragColor = vec4(ads(), 1);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result (I am also rendering the normals with another geometry shader for debugging purposes):

[image: rendering result]

The artifacts on the cube are wrong, and the "shadows" on the circle also moves a bit when I move the camera around (change the view matrix).

Any obvious errors in my GLSL code?

Comment: It looks correct to me, but the shininess value is very small. What happens if you set it to, for example, 50?

Comment: This make it looks good for the sphere (that is I cannot see anything wrong with it when I move the camera around it), but the artifacts are still there for the box.

Comment: Then I would check the box model and make sure that its correct. Perhaps the box have double surfaces and the moving artifacts is because of z-fighting?

Comment: Hmm. I remade the box using a few less subdivisions in blender and made the "shading" in blender "smooth". Now it all looks good.. Not sure I understand why. Anyway, thanks for leading me  on the right track and confirming my code!